# How can I list all collections in the MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

In the MongoDB shell, how do I list all collections for the current database that I'm using?

Answer (score 1358, accepted):

You can do...

JavaScript (shell):

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Node.js:

```
db.listCollections()
```

Non-JavaScript (shell only):

```
show collections
```

The reason I call that non-JavaScript is because:

```
$ mongo prodmongo/app --eval "show collections"
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: prodmongo/app
2016-10-26T19:34:34.886-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell eval):1:5

$ mongo prodmongo/app --eval "db.getCollectionNames()"
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: prodmongo/app
[
    "Profiles",
    "Unit_Info"
]
```

If you really want that sweet, sweet `show collections` output, you can:

```
$ mongo prodmongo/app --eval "db.getCollectionNames().join('\n')"
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: prodmongo/app
Profiles
Unit_Info
```

Comment: Nice feature. You can iterate through the array of names to do something else (e.g. remove all items from the collections).

Comment: [`db.getCollectionNames()` was removed in favor of `db.listCollections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/meta/changes-from-1.0/)

Comment: Can we please get `db.listCollections()` as the answer shown here and checked in green?  Otherwise people are making the same mistake I did countless times when they come to this answer - and attempt to use `db.getCollectionNames` and the error comes back `db.collectionNames is not a function`.

Comment: @niftylettuce This question is about the MongoDB shell, not the node.js driver. [`db.getCollectionNames()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#db.getCollectionNames) is still the right answer for the shell.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I do not agree that the `node` answer here is not well placed! Please look at the google result rank and people like me come here with a node env wanting to have a quick solution. Node is widely used with mongo. But nevertheless, the node solution here does not work for me;(

Comment: db.getCollectionNames() will only show the first 100 collections, if you need more use 'show collections'

Answer (score 474):

```
> show collections
```

will list all the collections in the currently selected DB, as stated in the command line help (`help`).

Comment: You can't use the show collections output in a script, but one can do x=db.getCollectionNames() to get an array of all the names.

Comment: What do the two numbers listed after every collection mean? Two types of sizes? `content               1145.586MB / 1506.855MB` for example.

Comment: @Dan: I haven't used MongoDB in a while, but my best guess is that it's the size of the data stored in the collection vs. the total amount allocated to that collection (to handle minor updates and growth without having to constantly reallocate new space for the entire collection's contents).

Answer (score 314):

> How do I list all collections for the current database that I'm using?

### Three methods

- `show collections`
- `show tables`
- `db.getCollectionNames()`

---

#### To list all *databases*:

```
show dbs
```

#### To enter or use a given database:

```
use databasename
```

---

### To list all *collections*:

```
show collections
```

Output:

> ```
> collection1
> collection2
> system.indexes
> ```

(or)

```
show tables
```

Output:

> ```
> collection1
> collection2
> system.indexes
> ```

(or)

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Output:

> ```
> [ "collection1", "collection2", "system.indexes" ]
> ```

---

### To enter or use given collection

```
use collectionname
```

Comment: nope, `use` is to use a database, nothing to do with collections

Comment: we can also use db.collections

Answer (score 56):

`> show tables`

It gives the same result as Cameron's answer.

Answer (score 36):

Apart from the options suggested by other people:

```
show collections  // Output every collection
show tables
db.getCollectionNames() // Shows all collections as a list
```

There is also another way which can be really handy if you want to know how each of the collections was created (for example, it is a capped collection with a particular size):

```
db.system.namespaces.find()
```

Answer (score 27):

First you need to use a database to show all collection/tables inside it.

```
>show dbs
users 0.56787GB
test (empty)
>db.test.help() // this will give you all the function which can be used with this db
>use users
>show tables //will show all the collection in the db
```

Answer (score 20):

Try:

```
help // To show all help methods
show dbs  // To show all dbs
use dbname  // To select your db
show collections // To show all collections in selected db
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use `show tables` or `show collections`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: How come is that? Based on other answers, that is suitable answer for this that actually might work. At least it is an attempt to answer. What it is, is an answer to very old question that already has multiple correct answers posted.

Answer (score 16):

```
 1. show collections; // Display all collections
 2. show tables     // Display all collections
 3. db.getCollectionNames();   // Return array of collection. Example :[ "orders", "system.profile" ]
```

Detailed information for every collection:

```
db.runCommand( { listCollections: 1.0, authorizedCollections: true, nameOnly: true } )
```

- For users with the required access (privileges that grant listCollections action on the database), the method lists the names of all collections for the database.
- For users without the required access, the method lists only the collections for which the users has privileges. For example, if a user has find on a specific collection in a database, the method would return just that collection.

To list collections list based on a search string.

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (CollectionName) { return /<Search String>/.test(CollectionName) })
```

**Example:**  Find all collection having "import" in the name

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (CollectionName) { return /import/.test(CollectionName) })
```

Comment: Can I get the list of collection which contains some name like filter

Comment: @Praveen - I've updated my answer to include answer to you case. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Amitesh. I wrote my script  db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName) {
    if (collName.startsWith("TestCollection_")) {
        print("droping index for " + collName);
        db.getCollection(collName).dropIndex("ts_1");

    }
});

Answer (score 14):

I think one of the biggest confusions is the difference between what you can do with `mongo` (or an interactive/hybrid shell) vs. `mongo --eval` (or a pure JavaScript shell). I keep these helpful documents handy:

- [Differences Between Interactive and Scripted `mongo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo)
- [Mongo Shell Command Helpers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#command-helpers)

Here is an example of scripting what you might otherwise do with `show` commands:

```
# List all databases and the collections in them

mongo --eval "
    db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(
        function(v, i){
            print(
                v + '\n\t' +
                db.getSiblingDB(v).getCollectionNames().join('\n\t')
            )
        }
    )
"
```

Note: That works really well as a one-liner. (But it looks terrible on Stack Overflow.)

```
mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(v, i){print(v+'\n\t'+db.getSiblingDB(v).getCollectionNames().join('\n\t'))})"
```

Answer (score 13):

The following commands on mongoshell are common.

```
show databases
show collections
```

Also,

```
show dbs
use mydb
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Sometimes it's useful to see all collections as well as the indexes on the collections which are part of the overall namespace:

Here's how you would do that:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
    indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
    print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
    printjson(indexes);
});
```

Between the three commands and this snippet, you should be well covered!

Answer (score 12):

The command used for displaying all the collections in the MongoDB database is

```
show collections
```

Before running the `show collections` command you have to select the database:

```
use mydb // mydb is the name of the database being selected
```

To see all the databases, you can use the command

```
show dbs // Shows all the database names present
```

For more information, visit see *[Getting Started](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/)*.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to show all collections from the MongoDB shell (command line), use the shell helper,

```
show collections
```

that shows all collections for the current database.
If you want to get all collection lists from your application then you can use the MongoDB database method

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

For more information about the MongoDB shell helper, you can see *[`mongo` Shell Quick Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/)*.

Answer (score 8):

```
> show dbs        
anuradhfirst  0.000GB
local         0.000GB
> use anuradhfirst
switched to db anuradhfirst
> show collections
record
```

- connect with the MongoDB database using `mongo`. This will start the connection.
- then run `show dbs` command. This will show you all exiting/available databases.
- then select the `database` you want. In the above it is `anuradhfirst`. Then run `use anuradhfirst`. This will switch to the database you want.
- then run `show collections` command. This will show all the `collections` inside your selected database.

Comment: This answer is showing the correct steps to get to the list of collections.

Answer (score 6):

For switching to the database.

By:

**use {your_database_name}** example:

```
use friends
```

where `friends` is the name of your database.

Then write:

```
db.getCollectionNames()
show collections
```

This will give you the name of collections.

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 4):

On >=2.x, you can do

```
db.listCollections()
```

On 1.x you can do

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Comment: as @JohnnyHK [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866041/how-to-list-all-collections-in-the-mongo-shell#comment-57467037) this only applies to the **node driver** and not the **mongo shell** per OP question

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I don't use Node. This works perfectly for me inside mongo shell. I wonder why it would not?

Comment: I'm running MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6, and when I run `db.getCollectionNames()` I get `[ "users" ]` because I have a users collection. If I try `db.listCollections()` then it results in `[thread1] TypeError: db.listCollections is not a function :
@(shell):1:1`

Answer (score 3):

**List all collections from the `mongo` shell:**

> - db.getCollectionNames()
> - show collections
> - show tables
>
> **Note: Collections will show from current database where you are in**
>   **currently**

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 2):

> show collections

This command usually works on the MongoDB shell once you have switched to the database.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone uses **Python & PyMongo**:

`db.list_collection_names()`

Answer (score 1):

> For MongoDB 3.0 deployments using the WiredTiger storage engine, if
>   you run `db.getCollectionNames()` from a version of the mongo shell
>   before 3.0 or a version of the driver prior to 3.0 compatible version,
>   `db.getCollectionNames()` will return no data, even if there are
>   existing collections.

For further details, please refer to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#considerations).

Comment: [Related meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394510/copy-from-documentation-and-mentioning-source-not-enough/394511#394511).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command from the `mongo` shell:

```
show collections
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

I use `listCollections` (supports MongoDB 3.0 and up) for this purpose.

Example:

```
db.runCommand({ listCollections: 1, filter: {}, nameOnly: true });
```

To fetch more information like the index of the collection:

```
db.runCommand({ listCollections: 1, filter: {}, nameOnly: false });
```

To print just the collection names:

```
db.runCommand({ listCollections: 1, filter: {}, nameOnly: true }).cursor.firstBatch.forEach(v => {print(v.name)})
```

I feel this provides more flexibility.

Read more: *[listCollections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/)*

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> show collections
> ```

or

> ```
> show tables
> ```

or

> ```
> db.getCollectionNames();
> ```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?