# How to list all databases in the mongo shell?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I know how to [list all collections in a particular database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866041/how-to-list-all-collections-in-the-mongo-shell), but how do I list all available databases in MongoDB shell?

Answer (score 453, accepted):

Listing all the databases in mongoDB console is using the command `show dbs`.

For more information on mongo shell commands, refer the [Mongo Shell Quick Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/mongo-shell/).

Comment: And for anyone (like me) that has just installed mongodb and are confused that running `db` shows the current database is `test` but this is not listed via any of the comnmands on this page that is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/q/38726310/73226

Comment: How on earth do you get to the shall though :/

Comment: @JamieHutber you get so shell by typing `mongo` on the command line (of `mongo --nodb` to not connect to a database)

Comment: Yeah I had to come here for something as simple as `show dbs` because I when I went to the docs I simply could not find the `show dbs` command anywhere. The 'docs' can be pretty frustrating at times.

Comment: That command does not work in a `--eval`, just on an interactive shell. This answer's options does work (output format is different though) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32192253/1837991

Comment: I get this when I run in MongoDB Pod terminal in Red Hat OpenShift:   `"errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0, $db: \"admin\" }"`

Answer (score 96):

For database list:

```
show databases
show dbs
```

For table/collection list:

```
show collections
show tables
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Answer (score 67):

For MongoDB shell version 3.0.5 insert the following command in the shell:

```
db.adminCommand('listDatabases')
```

or alternatively:

```
db.getMongo().getDBNames()
```

Comment: if you are in your shell and only want names: `mongo admin --quiet -u <mongodb_admin> -p [<password>] --eval 'db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(db){print(db)})'` hth

Answer (score 50):

From the command line issue

```
mongo --quiet --eval  "printjson(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))"
```

which gives output

```
{
    "databases" : [
        {
            "name" : "admin",
            "sizeOnDisk" : 978944,
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "local",
            "sizeOnDisk" : 77824,
            "empty" : false
        },
        {
            "name" : "meteor",
            "sizeOnDisk" : 778240,
            "empty" : false
        }
    ],
    "totalSize" : 1835008,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

to obtain a vertical list of all databases for downstream processing do this

```
mongo --quiet --eval  "printjson(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))" | jq  '.databases[].name' | tr -d '"'
```

which gives below output listing all databases

```
admin
local
meteor
```

Comment: Best solution here for running something automated (without going into mongo shell mode first)

Comment: Based on this answer I came up with `listDatabases="$(mongo --quiet --eval  "printjson(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))")"; ( while IFS=$'\t' read -r size name; do printf '%s\t%s\n' "$name" "$(numfmt --to=iec <<<"$size")"; done < <(jq -r '.databases[] | [.sizeOnDisk, .name] | @tsv' <<<"$listDatabases" | sort -rn); printf -- '-\t-\n'; printf "TOTAL\t%s\n" "$(jq -r .totalSize <<<"$listDatabases" | numfmt --to=iec)" ) | column -t -s$'\t'` to list all databases, sorted by size and the total at the end.

Answer (score 19):

To list mongodb database on shell

```
 show databases     //Print a list of all available databases.
 show dbs   // Print a list of all databases on the server.
```

Few more basic commands

```
use <db>    // Switch current database to <db>. The mongo shell variable db is set to the current database.
show collections    //Print a list of all collections for current database.
show users  //Print a list of users for current database.
show roles  //Print a list of all roles, both user-defined and built-in, for the current database.
```

Answer (score 10):

Couple of commands are there to list all dbs in MongoDB shell.

first , launch Mongodb shell using 'mongo' command.

> mongo

Then use any of the below commands to list all the DBs.

- show dbs
- show databases
- db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 , nameOnly : true} )

[image: A snap shot]

For more details please check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MongoDB official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/), for MongoDB 4+, you can list database name only by running `db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1, , nameOnly: true } )` against the *admin* database.

If you are using MongoDB Cloud, you need to connect to your MongoDB deployment first. In that case, you can run this command `mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.<your-connection-string>.mongodb.net" --apiVersion 1 --username <your-user-name>` in your terminal.

```html
Atlas atlas-xxxxxx-shard-0 [primary] test> db.adminCommand({listDatabases:1 , nameOnly: true})
{
  databases: [
    { name: 'sample_airbnb' },
    { name: 'sample_analytics' },
    { name: 'sample_geospatial' },
    { name: 'sample_guides' },
    { name: 'sample_mflix' },
    { name: 'sample_restaurants' },
    { name: 'sample_supplies' },
    { name: 'sample_training' },
    { name: 'sample_weatherdata' },
    { name: 'admin' },
    { name: 'local' }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: xxxxxxxxxx, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: xxxxxxxxxx, i: 1 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have found one solution, where admin()/others didn't worked.**

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec)
async function test() {
  var res = await exec('mongo  --eval "db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 }         
)" --quiet')
  return { res }
}

test()
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('All dbs', JSON.parse(resp.res.stdout).databases)
  })
test()
```