# Mongodb : why show dbs does not show my databases?

Tags: mongodb

I have setup mongodb 64bits on Windows. I ran server and client successfully.

But when I type:

```
show dbs
```

Output is

```
local  0.000GB
```

Why ? show dbs is supposed to list all databases at least the default one "test"
am I wrong ?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Although you may be in the test database by default, the database does not actually get created until you insert a document into a collection in the database which will implicitly create the collection and the database.

Comment: Something so simple, yet so important (and confusing to new folks). Thank you