# Mongo: show dbs doesn't show the test db. Why?

Tags: mongodb

When I first type `mongo`, I see "connecting to : test". However, when I type `show dbs`, it does not show me the `test` db. I can still see `local`, as well as some other dbs that I created... but not `test`. Any hints why?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726310/mongodb-why-show-dbs-does-not-show-my-databases

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you type `db` you will see that you are on database named test, but it won't be shown in list, that happens because test db doesn't contain any document it is empty. You need to create at least one document in test database if you want it to be shown in list after typing `show dbs`

Comment: Worked like a charm!