# Why is a current database not listed in `show dbs`?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB shell:

```
> show dbs;
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
> db
test
```

Does `show dbs` show all existing databases? Does `db` shows the current database? Why is `test` not listed in `show dbs`? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb : why show dbs does not show my databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726310/mongodb-why-show-dbs-does-not-show-my-databases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current database needs to have some documents & collections in them, for them to be listed. Try creating a collection in `test` db and insert a document. It'll then be listed.