# how to show my users collection with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm sorry for this (peraphs) stupid question ... I install meteor and mongodb in my windows computer and i start to write some apps. I don't understand how to use mongo for shoving my db app ... i open one shell in my app dir and launch mongod, in one more shell in the same folder i start mongo.

> show dbs
>   local
>   use local
>   switched to db local
>   show collections
>   startup_log
>   system.indexes

Where are my collections? Where is users collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor uses a library called [Minimongo](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html) that's why it doesn't display if you run `show dbs` on your mongo shell.

By default it points to port `3001` hence if you are using [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) you can just make the set up to watch that port.

Answer (score 3):

When your app is running use this command on a separate command line `mongo 127.0.0.1:3001`

Meteor keeps the collections in this server. After you run mongo on this server, by writing `use meteor` you can use db specific to your running app. And then you can display your collections with `db.getCollectionNames()`

Comment: Omg ... i start robomongo with this connection and i finaly see my collections ...

Answer (score 1):

To display all your MongoDB collections using the shell, you may check this answer:
[How to list all collections in the mongo shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866041/how-to-list-all-collections-in-the-mongo-shell)

You may also use a MongoDB GUI Tool such Robomongo

Comment: Yes I see this post, I don't understand how to "connect" with the app db, i see only local db and there is no collections

Comment: for further users, to get the configuration details, and the connection string, you can run: `meteor mongo -U`

By the way, meteor stores data in server-side collections, client-side collections and collections accessible by both side, which can be a bit confusing at first. I think this [guide](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/databases-part-1/) may help