# mongo shell - Accessing a databases collection

Tags: mongodb

## The problem

I have successfully launched the `mongo` shell on my MAC OSX environment. I am resourcing the following links and documentation to figure out the simple task of getting into a database, then a collection, then querying documents within the collection:
[Accessing a database](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/query/) from MongoDB documentation,
[Accessing a collection and documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866041/how-to-list-all-collections-in-the-mongo-shell), here on Stackoverflow, and [Accessing a collection](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_query_document.htm) from Tutorials Point.

I created and loaded the database through the `PyMongo` API. This successfully created a database named `UCI-Database`, a collection named `income`, and filled it with a bunch of documents (rows) from `.csv` document.

## So far ..

These are my results...

```
Blakes-MacBook-Pro:nosql bmc$ mongo 127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.4
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-05-16T12:22:10.147-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-05-16T12:22:10.147-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-05-16T12:22:10.147-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-05-16T12:22:10.147-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-05-16T12:22:10.147-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-05-16T12:22:10.147-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
> show dbs
UCI-Database   0.006GB
admin          0.000GB
local          0.000GB
test-database  0.000GB
> use UCI-Database
switched to db UCI-Database
> show collections
income
profiles
>
```

And `income` is for sure the collection I created to store my rows from UCI's Adult income repository. As stated in the [mongo db documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

```
db.collection.find(query, projection)
```

Is the syntax to query a collection.

## My best attempt

```
> db.UCI-Database.income.find({"age":35})
2017-05-16T16:38:00.846-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: Database is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
>
```

Any feedback is helpful.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you are not doing

```
db.collection.find(query, projection)
```

To query the collection you want remove the database name from the command, i.e.

```
use UCI-Database
db.income.find({"age":35})
```

Comment: It worked. This was a very helpful comment. Do you have any good resources for learning to query and become more comfortable with mongodb? Things like `count` and `distinct` like in SQL?

Comment: @bmc these classes offered by https://university.mongodb.com/ are pretty great. I recommend M101 course to get up and running with mongodb