# How to list MongoDB items of a Local Database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost, mongo-shell

I've already [done my research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866041/how-can-i-list-all-collections-in-the-mongodb-shell) and have gotten so far...

By entering the commands on mongoDB shell or node, [this shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yijbz.png):
[image: 2]]

Now the problem is that I actually have users in this DB because I'm testing this on an application on port 3000 localhost. When I try to register the same user a second time, an error shows up, saying that this entry is duplicate.

TL;DR: Mongo says DB is empty when it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the database `testForAuth`, use the command `db.users.find()` and it should print out all the users.

Comment: Thanks! It actually worked! First time I used mongoDB, sorry for the newbie question (^.^*)
  Edit: If I may ask do you have experience in setting an online database?

Comment: No worries glad I could help! Yes I do, I use MongoDB Atlas mostly. Heres a link to get started https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/ .

Comment: I dreaded I was gonna ask this, but I read the docs and I still need your help (^.^*)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62269624/error-connecting-to-atlas-free-cluster-mongodb 
@brendan