# How to get the list of my database's collection names

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have briefly searched through the internet but i haven't found anything useful.
My problem is that i can't retrieve the list of my database collections with the the function :
**db.listCollections()**.

---

So simply what i did is the following:

```
const db = client.db(db_name);
let colls = db.listCollections() // also tried db.listCollections({}, {nameOnly: true});
```

But all i get is a large object that doesn't mention any collections. Am i missing something big? I assumed that i would retrieve an array but no luck to that, sooo... can anyone quickly help out here?

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866041/how-can-i-list-all-collections-in-the-mongodb-shell to check how to see list of database collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so apparently by adding :

```
let colls = db.listCollections().toArray();
```

was enough. But i dont know why something like that is not mentioned in the documentation...

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/index.html#db-getcollectionnames

Comment: Yea but this function works only in the mongo shell and not for node. Most of the commands that i had checked would work specifically in the mongo shell. Is there a way to get and store the mongo shell's output from nodejs?